# 'docker compose up' hangs forever (usually), even with V2 despite high entropy (Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm having issues with the `docker compose up` command.

So I've recently created a fresh Ubuntu OS installation and I've been setting up my development environment. I've installed Docker and ***mostly*** everything seems to be working fine. Bringing up single containers works as expected, for example:

`~$ docker run hello-world`

```
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

However, when I try to use the `docker compose up` command it just hangs indefinitely and doesn't do anything. It doesn't show an error or anything, it just accepts the command, prints a new line to the terminal and hangs.

I've spent a whole day trying to find the issue, including ensuring the system has high entropy, installing `haveged` and that I'm also using Docker Compose V2, all as suggested by this thread..

[docker-compose up hangs forever. How to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59941911/docker-compose-up-hangs-forever-how-to-debug)

I've allocated the docker engine more than 24 cores, 64 GB of memory, and 400 GiB of virtual disk, (also tried a smaller virtual disk of only 20 GB), but this seems to make no difference.

The Ubuntu OS is installed on a 2TB NVMe drive but the rest of the system information is as follows:

```
Hardware Model: Micro-Star International CO.,Ltd. MS-7C60
Memory: 128.0 GiB
Processor: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3970x 320core processor x 64
Disk Capacity: 8.2 TB

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version: 42.5
Windowing System: Wayland
```

`~$ docker version`

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.5
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.19.8
 Git commit:        bc4487a
 Built:             Wed Apr 26 16:21:07 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          23.0.5
  API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.8
  Git commit:       94d3ad6
  Built:            Wed Apr 26 16:21:07 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

`~$ docker compose version`

```
Docker Compose version v2.17.3
```

I'm not a very experienced Ubuntu user, and although I've used Docker a lot, I do not claim to be an expert, so any and all help, suggestions or comments are gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Im having this same issue with Arch linux, docker compose works fine on the same machine with Ubuntu OS.

Comment: After some debugging and running the containers separately, I realized that I had a file that was supposed to be included but its gitignored. It turned out I had placed it in the wrong spot, under "/.secrets" instead of "/secrets". Once I fixed that, everything started working fine. By the way, I think my system's "entropy" is 256, which is below the 1000 threshold mentioned in other questions. So, I'd recommend trying to run each container individually to figure out what's missing.